# Required to calculate the number of minutes as an int, then the seconds as a double. method should use a format string in Java

Tags: java, string.format

I am in the process of creating a public method String `toString()`.

The requirement is to take a randomly generated number which is tenths of seconds (for example 6500) and convert these into int minutes and double seconds.

I need to use this format string: `"%s \t %d mins %.1f secs \t %s"`.

I am struggling to get my head round this as I have created the following method:

```
public String toString()
   {
      int time = 6500;
      int minutes = time / 600;
      double seconds = (time % 600) / 600;
      String displayTime = String.format("%s \t %d mins" + minutes, seconds  + "%.1f secs \t %s");

return this.getName() + ", " + displayTime;
    }
```

I am receiving an error:

```
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 'd'
```

It would need to return the below:

> John Doe      19 mins 8.2 secs

I am new to this site and Java, so any help is extremely helpful.

Comment: Java [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) will do this for you. Just find any tutorial on Java Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code, especially this line:

```
String displayTime = String.format("%s \t %d mins" + minutes, seconds  + "%.1f secs \t %s");
```

to:

```
String name = getName(); //to get the string "John Doe"
String displayTime = String.format("%s \t %d mins %.1f secs \t", name, mins, seconds);

return name + "," + displayName; //we already have the name defined
```

For this to work, the variable names should be at the end and not in the middle. Also, the number of "%"'s in your string should be equal to the variable. For example, the first %s in my answer above is for the name, the next %d is for the minutes, and the last %.1f is for the seconds upto one decimal point.

You should use this link to help you understand this concept more: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format

Feel free to ask me in the comments if my answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks I have tried this and it now works but I am not able to get the seconds correct  John Smith   24 mins 519.0 secs when using the double seconds it should show 24 mins 51.9 secs

Comment: @R1c0 that would have something to do with your value for the `seconds` variables, meaning you should play around with those: try this: `double seconds = (time % 600) / 6000;` instead, although I cannot guarantee if it will work.

Comment: No problem and thanks I have been working on this too long and didn't  include the .0.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

String.format() does not work this way.
For example : String.format("%s = %d", "joe", 35);
The variables names must be at the end separated by commas, not in the middle of the String.